# React native - position a view beyond the react navigation bottom tabs it is a child of

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to make the bottom sheet touch the bottom of the screen rather than the bottom of the tab bar.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiVBh.png)

- Attempts to increase the z-index and position it further down are fruitless as the View will not overlap the bottom bar, it will always go behind it.
- I tried to wrap it in a Modal component, which fixes the alignment, but then you can not interact with the map.

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom bottom sheet. You can use this package

[react-native-actions-sheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-actions-sheet)

I have used this in many applications. This will resolve all of your issues. As this package is comfortable in iOS and android both.

Comment: Like a modal, this blocks touch interactions with the everything that is not the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the bottom sheet libraries which are present in react native. Few of which I have used is:

1. [react-native-raw-bottom-sheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-raw-bottom-sheet) //my choice
2. [react-native-actions-sheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-actions-sheet)

You can also check [this](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/) out

Comment: Like a modal, these also block touch interactions with everything that is not the sheet.